# can't compile android applications, gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to setup Android Studio, but when I click build/run, I get an error:

```
 Error:org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip'.: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip'.
```

in gradle settings, I have the 
Path: C:/gradle-1.10/bin

but the interface says 'Gradle location is incorrect'. Any suggestions what's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Try using gradle wrapper as it is recommended setting for Android projects in AS. You don't have to install gradke externally

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding Wrapper in your build.gradle file:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.10'
}
```

Then, run the build command from command line:

```
./gradlew build
```

You can also follow this link as reference: http://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle-android/